# WiFi upload book can not open the web page

Tags: ios

I tested my app on iOS8.1,iOS8.4,iOS10.0 ,iOS10.2 and iOS10.1.1. Only on iOS10.1.1 device, it didn't work. Once i turn on the developer setting "Allow Http Services",it worked.but in other similar apps, its "wifi-uploading"  always works well.Can anyone tell me why? thanks!

Comment: I believe it's related to `App Transport Security Settings`. I suggest you to look into that. Please let me know if that's not the reason.

Comment: thanks for your answer!  I have already set "Allow Arbitrary Loads" to "YES",but it doesn't work. But,even if i did not set it, my app can work well on other iOS version i tested, except iOS10.1.1.

Comment: I find it!  in  **"cocoaHttpserver"** ,there is a rewritable function **"- (BOOL)isSecureServer；"** 。when i first use it, i returned "YES";because i known  that is APPLE's suggesting。but i  did not known that means a lot of working, and in fact ,i need not do that. return "NO",all is ok! Thanks again!